Snowflake SQL | How to sum over distinct values in one pass?
I am working with survey response data, where a user could have taken the survey multiple times. Users have a "weight" assigned to them, which is an integer. I am trying to calculate the sum of user_weight by city, making sure I don't double count the user_weight for users who have taken the survey multiple times.
Using the example data I provided here, note that each of the users here took the survey twice.

I can calculate the correct city_weight using a two-pass approach. Below is snowflake sql code using a CTE that de-dupes the (city, user, user_weight) tuples first and then sums up the user_weight by city. This approach works, and I get the correct weights (of 150 for chicago, and 55 for denver).
Is there a one-pass approach to solve this problem?
create or replace temp table temp as 
select 1 as response_id, 1 as user_id, 50 as user_weight, 'chicago' as city
union select 2, 1, 50, 'chicago'
union select 3, 2, 100, 'chicago'
union select 4, 2, 100, 'chicago'
union select 5, 3, 30, 'denver'
union select 6, 3, 30, 'denver'
union select 7, 4, 25, 'denver'
union select 8, 4, 25, 'denver'
;

with base as (
select
 distinct
    city,
    user_id,
    user_weight
 from
    temp
)
select
    city,
    sum(user_weight) as city_weight
from
    base
group by city
;



Possibly combine the row_number window function with QUALIFY?

I'm not sure there is a good way to do this without a CTE and Snowflake doesn't really do these operations sequential with 1 or 2 passes, as such, so I don't see any reason to change what you have.  The row_number and qualify would be a different way to accomplish the distinct portion of your CTE, and QUALIFY happens after the select, so it can't really be used in conjunction with a GROUP BY like you'd want.  There might be some fancy way to do this without a CTE, but it would likely end up costing you on performance.

is it possible for the same user to enter multiple weight values with each survey submission. if so, how do you want to handle that (take the first, last, or average)?

@HaleemurAli the weight values do not vary for the user in each survey submission.

You can dedupe with a group by, then run a windowed sum on top of that, then add a distinct to collapse the window. That said, what you have is perfectly fine and more self-explanatory
select distinct 
       city,
       sum(user_weight) over (partition by city) as city_weight
from temp
group by city, user_id, user_weight;


great solution. might be worth it to specify the frame explicitly as unbounded preceding / following, since the default window frame can vary based on whether the query specifies an order by clause.

@HaleemurAli For non-rank-based functions such as sum, the default behavior is predictable, intuitive, and consistent across databases, so I prefer to leave the frame definition out unless necessitated by the problem. I'd agree with your suggestion for rank-based functions, particularly first_value() and least_value() though.
